# Getting POST response in a Get HttpURLConnection request

Tags: android, post, get, httpurlconnection

I don't know why but i'm getting a POST response when i'm doing a GET request, here's my method:

```
public String performGetBrandCall(String requestURL) {

    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + MainActivity.TOKEN);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d(TAG, "Response Code: " + responseCode);


        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK || responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                response+=line;
            }
        } else {
            if (responseCode >= 400 && responseCode < 500){
                String line;
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response+=line;
                }
            } else {
                response="";
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```

I'm adding a header by using setRequestProperty, is the only "parameter" i set to the request but i'm receiving the post response and i don't know why. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

According to Android Developers Guide:

**SetDoOutput** Sets the flag indicating whether this URLConnection allows output. It cannot be set after the connection is established.

This method have to be called only if you are using a POST request... if you are doing a GET request and SetDoOutput is true, your request will be a POST request.

I only delete that line and now i'm getting my GET response:

```
public String performGetCall(String requestURL) {

    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "+ MainActivity.TOKEN);
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d(TAG, "Response Code: "+responseCode);

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK || responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                response+=line;
            }
        } else {
            if (responseCode >= 400 && responseCode < 500){
                String line;
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response+=line;
                }
            } else {
                response="";
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```